# Definition of "symmetric bilinear (real) form indefinite"

Tags: linear-algebra, definition, bilinear-form

In my studies I use these definition:

Def.: $f \in \mathscr{B}_ \Bbb{R}((e \times e),  \Bbb{R}) $, $f $ is symmetric bilinear (real) form positive definite if
1) $\forall x \in e(f(x,x)\geq0)$
2) $\forall x \in e(f(x,x)=0 \leftrightarrow x=0)$

Def.: $f \in \mathscr{B}_ \Bbb{R}((e \times e),  \Bbb{R}) $, $f $ is symmetric bilinear (real) form negative definite if
1) $\forall x \in e(f(x,x)\leq0)$
2) $\forall x \in e(f(x,x)=0 \leftrightarrow x=0)$

Def.: $f \in \mathscr{B}_ \Bbb{R}((e \times e),  \Bbb{R}) $, $f $ is symmetric bilinear (real) form postive semi-definite if
1) $\forall x \in e(f(x,x)\geq0)$
2) $\exists z \in e(z \neq 0 \wedge f(z,z)=0 )$

Def.: $f \in \mathscr{B}_ \Bbb{R}((e \times e),  \Bbb{R}) $, $f $ is symmetric bilinear (real) form negative semi-definite if
1) $\forall x \in e(f(x,x)\leq0)$
2) $\exists z \in e(z \neq 0 \wedge f(z,z)=0 )$

I need definition of "symmetric bilinear (real) form indefinite"...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do the notations $0_{+\mathbb{R}}$ and $0_{+e}$ mean that the zero is the identity element in the respective additive groups? Frankly, I find them redundant. I would simply write $0$, since the context always makes clear which zero it is.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro, of course! Ok.. I edit my post! ;) Thanks for hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indefinite if it is neither of the above. For example, in $\mathbb R^2 \times \mathbb R^2$: $$x^T\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&-1 \end{bmatrix}x.$$

Comment: @ dafinguzman, therefore $f$ is symmetric bilinear (real) form indefinite if: 
1) $f$ is not symmetric bilinear (real) form positive definite

2) $f$ is not symmetric bilinear (real) form negative definite

3) $f$ is not symmetric bilinear (real) form positive semi-definite

4) $f$ is not symmetric bilinear (real) form negative semi-definite

Correct? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Yes. Another way to say it is that its quadratic form takes positive and negative values.

Comment: ok, of course! Thanks soo much! :)

Comment: Would the downvoter say why? I'd like to know if I'm wrong.

Comment: I don't know! ;) Thanks soo much! :)